# Improving performance of Overpass area search queries

Tags: performance, query, api, overpass-api

I am building an application that retrieves lists of location names within geographical boundaries like cities and postal codes. The queries take up to 15 seconds to complete and I would like to make them more performant if possible to reduce querying time.  Here is one query to retrieve street names within a city:

```
[out:csv("name";false)];area[name="Hirschau"]->.small;area["ISO3166-1:alpha2"="DE"]->.big;way(area.small)(area.big)[highway][name];out;
```

This retrieves towns/villages within a zipcode

```
[out:csv("name";false)];area["ISO3166-1:alpha2"="DE"]->.big;area[postal_code="92224"]->.small;node[place~"village|town"](area.small)(area.big);out;
```

Is there a way to make these more performant? I have tried switching the order of the areas but it does not seem to affect querying time.

Comment: On your own self-hosted Overpass instance or a third-party one?

Comment: I use overpass-api.de/api/interpreter Would hosting my own instance be faster?